# Determine whether each sequence converges or diverges. If it converges find the limit.

Tags: calculus

> $${b_n}= \frac{(\sin(n))^{2}}{3^{n}} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin x^{2}}{3^{x}} = \frac{2\sin x(\cos x)}{\ln(3)3^{x}}$$

I feel like I am doing it correctly; the solution is that it converges to zero; however I don't see how this is true. Is it because $2\cos x$ is oscillating back from $(2,-2)$?

> $${c_n}= \frac{9(n+1)!}{n!}$$

I understand that the limit diverges because $(n+1)!$ is greater than $(n)!$ and therefore diverges, but I'm not sure if in an exam I would need to show how this is true.

$${e_n}= \frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$

The answer is that it converges to zero; I would approach this problem by doing L'Hopitals Rule and get

$${e_n}= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}} \;=\; \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}= 0$$

I have an exam tomorrow and I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out. Thank you!

Comment: In the first one, you took the derivative wrong. $$((\sin(x))^2)'=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$and it goes to $0$ because $\cos$ just oscillates while the $3^x$ grows very fast. For the second one, just use that $(n+1)!=(n+1)\cdot (n!)$

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sequence converges to zero because you can squeeze it between zero and a sequence that converges to zero:

$$ 0 \leq \frac{\sin(n)^2}{3^n} \leq \frac{1}{3^n}. $$

The second sequence is just

$$ c_n = 9\frac{(n+1)!}{n!} = 9(n+1) $$

so it goes to infinity.

Regarding the third sequence, you can solve it using L'Hopital because

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2\sqrt{x}}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} = 0.$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand how it becomes $9(n+1)$. is it because the numerator would be doing $(n+1)! (n)(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)...(3)(2)(1)$ and so the denominator cancels out with the top?

Comment: @Bazfred: $(n+1)! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot n \cdot (n+1)$ while $n! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot n$ so if you divide them you get $\frac{(n+1)!}{n!} = n+1$.